# Is there a distribution such that sum of its iid variables have uniform distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

This question occurred when thinking about the [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem) so I could somehow generate random delays to make load on a server more uniform instead of a big spike when a large number of requests is generated at the same time.

Is there an uniformly distributed $X$ such that

$$ X = \sum_i^n x_i  $$

and what is the distribution of iid $x_i$ if it exists?

Comment: Actually you are asking wheter the uniform distribution is infinitely divisible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability) , to which the answer is no.

Comment: If the question is "does there exist any n for which X is a sum of n iid variables?" then the answer "no" does not follow from the fact that the uniform distribution is not infinitely divisible.

Answer (score 0):

Leander Tilsted Kristensen posted an answer in a comment. Thanks!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)

> In probability theory, a probability distribution is infinitely divisible if it can be expressed as the probability distribution of the sum of an arbitrary number of independent and identically distributed random variables.
>
> ...
>
> The uniform distribution and the binomial distribution are not infinitely divisible (...)